# css border with triangle shape

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

Is there any way to create the border on the left with css ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using CSS; you are just layering a Parallelogram and a Rectangle:

```css
.espanolIcon
{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.rectangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green; 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 40px;
}

.arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transform: skew(22deg); 
    transform: skew(22deg); 
    border-radius: 0px 0px 30px 40px;
    
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="espanolIcon">
    <div class="rectangle"><h1>Espanol</h1></div>
    <div class="arrow-left"></div>
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: I like the use of `skew` here.

Comment: :) Thank you, I really liked your solution, it was clean. :)

Answer (score 2):

### Use a zero-dimension `:before` with thick, partial borders

By adjusting the top/bottom and left/right values of `border-width` on the `:before` pseudo-element, you can effectively change the skew of the triangle. The `left` position can then be changed to properly align the pseudo-element.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 14px; /* Should counter `left` value of `a:before` */
  padding: .5em 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font: bold 1em/1 sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background: #75bf41;
}
a:before {
  content: '\200B'; /* zero-width non-breaking space */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -14px; /* Adjust to align */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 14px 8px; /* Adjust top/bottom and left/right to skew */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #75bf41 #75bf41 transparent transparent; /* Triangle orientation. */
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Español</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Full css could work, but you should use .png as `background-image` or perhaps you could use .svg as you can animate and/or change every `point` or `pixel. You might be able to use just CSS`but it would take a lot of leveling and positioning and alot of layers of absolute and relative positioning. As Css would only change the `full` width of the element, and it can only be used to change the width of elements. What you can do is use .svg, you could map every pixel which could be animated.

Comment: is this a comment or answer?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it using borders and pseudo elements.

```
<ul>
  <li class="lang-item lang-item-6 lang-item-es">
    ::before
    <a>Español</a>
  </li>
</ul>

ul {
    position:relative;
}

.lang-item {
   text-align: right;
   position: relative;
}

.lang-item a {
   background: #76c53f;
   padding: 15px;
   color: #fff;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 14px;
 }

.lang-item::before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 101px;
    top: -15px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 40px solid #76C541;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x8au7xz/)